# SWT TableViewer with multiple icons in cells

Tags: java, swt, tableviewer

At first, I wanted to make several columns to contain certain flags for each table row. These flags are represented by images.

Since I would have quite a few columns like these, I figured it would be awesome to have just one column containing all these flags, one after another.

**Question:** Can I add more than one images/icons in a table cell via a `TableLabelProvider`, **or** am I obliged to unify my icons in a single image with all these icons next to eachother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to ITableLabelProvider [javadoc](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/ITableLabelProvider.html) overriding `Image getColumnImage(Object element, int columnIndex)` you will return a single image for the particular column. So I think you should assemble a single image from all your images and return it.

Comment: Yeah I thought so too. Gonna create images with an `ImageBuilder` and then just cache the built images. :-)